# WPF DataGrid how to get after adding a new row the values of the selected row - mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I know this is possibbly a new duplicate, but I didn't find any solution for my problem or maybe I got some logical disaster in my brain... Whatever, I got an Datagrid where I bind a Datatable to. Now I want to add a new row in the datagrid/datatable. This new row has to be inserted in my sqlite db. So I'am listening for the RowEditEnding Event to get those newly values but it looks like that the newly added row has to be first committed I think - so how can I commit without StackOverflowException and get those values?

WPF Datagrid

```
                      <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" 
                              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MlDb.Tbl_Technik}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding TechnicRow, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="InitializingNewItem">
                                <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="TeInitializingNewItem" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                                <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="TeRowEditEnding" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="TeSelectionChanged" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Technik ID" Width="70" Binding="{Binding Path=TechnikID}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Techniktyp" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Techniktyp}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anlage" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Path=Anlage}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Anlagengruppe" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Anlagengruppe}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Bemerkung" Width="110" Binding="{Binding Path=Bemerkung}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

And parts of my ViewModel looks like this:

```
public void TeInitializingNewItem(object sender, InitializingNewItemEventArgs e)
{ //Raised if a new row is added
  newRowTe = true;
}

    public void TeRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    { // 



        selectedRow = e.Row.GetIndex();

        if (newRowTe)
        {

            // this position would be great to get the values...
        }
        else
        {
            rowEditEndTe = true;

            DataRowCollection drc = MlDataSetCollection[0].Tbl_Technik.Rows;
            Tbl_TechnikRow notUpdatedRow = (Tbl_TechnikRow)drc[selectedRow];
            technicId = notUpdatedRow.TechnikID;
        }
    }

    public void TeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    { //

        if (rowEditEndTe)
        {
            DataGrid materialDg = (DataGrid)sender;
            materialDg.CommitEdit();

            DataRowCollection drc = MlDataSetCollection[0].Tbl_Technik.Rows;
            Tbl_TechnikRow updatedRow = (Tbl_TechnikRow)drc[selectedRow];

            UpdateTblTe(updatedRow);

            rowEditEndTe = false;
        }
        else if (newRowTe)
        {
            // here I would like to call my function to insert new row in sql db IF rows are changing (if the user changed to another ui element or time is down then I will do the insert command)
        }
    }
```

So is there a other event i can listen to? Or can somebody tell me how to get the values??

Thanks
        #endregion

Comment: You mention a `StackOverflowException` - where and when exactly does it appear?

Comment: This happens when I want manually do the commit edit like:

DataGrid materialDg = (DataGrid)sender;
materialDg.CommitEdit();

This happens in the TeRowEditEnding method, after if(newRowTe)

Comment: Maybe you can listen to the `DataTable.RowChanged` event instead? The problem is, `RowEditEnding` (as the name implies) is raised when the editing ends (in process) and not after the editing has ended (done). However, I'm not sure, if that's the right event.

Comment: Man this was the trick for my scenario . thanks a lot!!